# Can you explain odd behaviour of Boxing and Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

According to the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) the following code ought to cause a compile error:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GenericTest1 {

    // Add T-array of objects to collection<T>
    static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
        for (T o : a) {
            c.add(o);
        }
    }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
       Number[] na = new Number[100];
       Collection<Number> cn = new ArrayList<Number>();


       // This should work and does
       fromArrayToCollection( na, cn );


       Collection<String> cs = new ArrayList<String>();

       // This should fail to copile and does
       fromArrayToCollection( na, cs );
   }
}
```

and it does:

```
GenericTest1.java:25: error: method fromArrayToCollection in class GenericTest1 cannot be applied to given types;
       fromArrayToCollection( na, cs );
       ^
  required: T[],Collection<T>
  found: Number[],Collection<String>
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: String
    lower bounds: Number
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>fromArrayToCollection(T[],Collection<T>)
```

However, this compiles and runs perfectly.

```
public class GenericTest2 {

    // Test for equality of two objects of type T
    static <T> boolean testEquality(T first, T second ) {
        return first.equals( second );
    }


   public static void main( String[] args ) {
       // Should work
       System.out.println( testEquality( "One", "One" ) );

       // Shouldn't this refuse to compile ?
       System.out.println( testEquality( "One", 1 ) );

       // Shouldn't this refuse to compile ?
       Number one = new Integer( 1 );
       System.out.println( testEquality( "One", one ) );

   }
}
```

Output is :

```
true
false
false
```

Can anyone explain why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because `one`(`Number`) and `"One"`(`String`) are both `Object`s, as are `1`(`Integer` due to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)) and `"One"`(`String`). So `T` is evaluated to `Object`, equals gets called and returns `false`.
It does not work with the `Collection`(and other generics for that matter) [because  a `Collection<String>` can not be cast to a `Collection<Object>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 1):

`testEquality( "One", 1 )`

As a result of autoboxing, `1` here will be converted to `Integer(1)`, which is an object. Both `String("One")` and `Integer(1)` inherited `.equals` function from `Object`, thus it can compile without error.

Answer (score 0):

In your second test, the `1` will simply be boxed into an `Integer` instance, which is also an instance of `Object`.